# WhatsApp - How WhatsApp server stops/detects requests from unauthorized apps?

Tags: authentication, session, authorization, client-server, whatsapp

Every application that generates dynamic content must have a server whose address is embedded inside the application to enable communication with server.

Now in the case of `WhatsApp` definitely they have also embed the server's address inside the `WhatsApp` application. For example someone reverse engineer the `WhatsApp` `apk` and found the address of the server, as well as he also found the parameters and all the stuff that the application sends to the server (i-e session, token, authentication key etc etc) for successful communication, so is that mean he can use these same parameters structure and the server address in different third party app to play/communicate with the `WhatsApp` server? Because server is just an electronic device that works on the digital signals and thats it. Server don't know that these parameters are coming from the authorized `WhatsApp` `apk` or from third party `apk`.

If `yes`, then don't you guys think that there should be solution to that problem?

If `no`, then what are the techniques and algorithms they are using to stop requests from unauthorized/fake apps.

I believe not any employee from `WhatsApp` will answer here to share the algorithm, but i know SOF is full of geeks, if someone knows how `WhatsApp` stops these kind of issues please share, otherwise i will be still glad to know about the advice and ideas that you guys have in your mind for the best security practices.

How banking, paypal etc and messaging apps including WhatsApp works in that scenario and how they stop the issue that i described above?

**Important:**

I am not going to reverse engineer the `WhatsApp`, i am just creating a server and fighting with this issue to be solved to secure my server and only accept request from my app but stop requests from unauthorized/fake apps.

Thanks & respect to all in advance who will contribute.

Comment: Your `example` is possible and waiting for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent malicious reverse-engineering, resulting in a fake app pretending to be the real thing. While you are working on your server, you need to do defensive programming, that is, your server shouldn't assume that the request was sent via the app. So, if you protect your server against all kinds of malicious and deliberate misuses, then your server is safe.

However, that's easier said than done, because your project is developed by a finite amount of people and - if it becomes successful then - the audience contains a swarm of smart bad people.

You will therefore need to detect a subset of features that you need to absolutely protect against misuses and prioritize testing and improving those, by thinking with the mind of a fictional hacker, who would like to either gain unearned profits or do harm to your project. Schizophrenic, I know, but you need to do that on the server. You also need to improve the security of less than critical features, but at a lower priority and log the requests you get, so if SHTF, then you will have at least a chance to deduce what caused it and how.

If the phone app is in your hands as well, then you might implement some additional authentication for each version, like generating a version token for each user that downloads your app. Since the version token generator algorithm would not be in the hands of hackers, they would have to solve that on a per user basis, which is extremely laborius to solve this for several users if done by hand and if they work it out in a way to make it automatic, their solution would be viable only for a version.

So, there is no 100% accuracy in this area, but you can make life very hard and miserable for people payed to hack through your application.

Comment: So, you mean there is no way to stop that, and the only best practice is to secure the server?

Comment: @Sunny yes. For example if you have the exact code somehow reverse engineered, generated or written as in the app and all the credentials, then there is no way to distinguish your request from a valid request.

Comment: Then the fact is we don't have any way to even secure the server. Let say you secure the server by applying all the possible security algorithms and techniques, but if the server is receiving the right parameters from fake app, it means all the security practices on the server side are useless.

Comment: @Sunny I wouldn't view it this way. Yes, if the request is perfectly valid from all the points of view the server can validate against, then you cannot protect yourself against such a problem, however, it still protects you from a large amount of problems. A good analogy is the username-password. If I know your username and password for a site, then I can log in with your account. However, there is a lot of difficulty in finding out your username and password.